# Python runtime error with unknown test cases for t9spelling on Kattis

Tags: python, runtime-error, runtime

I was trying to solve this: https://open.kattis.com/problems/t9spelling
(Source: Kattis)

```
Test Case #1 (passed):
4
hi
yes
foo  bar
hello world

Output #1:
Case #1: 44 444
Case #2: 999337777
Case #3: 333666 6660 022 2777
Case #4: 4433555 555666096667775553
```

This is what I've tried:

```
import sys

def num(c):
    if c == 'a':
        return 2
    elif c == 'b':
        return 22
    elif c == 'c':
        return 222
    elif c == 'd':
        return 3
    elif c == 'e':
        return 33
    elif c == 'f':
        return 333
    elif c == 'g':
        return 4
    elif c == 'h':
        return 44
    elif c == 'i':
        return 444
    elif c == 'j':
        return 5
    elif c == 'k':
        return 55
    elif c == 'l':
        return 555
    elif c == 'm':
        return 6
    elif c == 'n':
        return 66
    elif c == 'o':
        return 666
    elif c == 'p':
        return 7
    elif c == 'q':
        return 77
    elif c == 'r':
        return 777
    elif c == 's':
        return 7777
    elif c == 't':
        return 8
    elif c == 'u':
        return 88
    elif c == 'v':
        return 888
    elif c == 'w':
        return 9
    elif c == 'x':
        return 99
    elif c == 'y':
        return 999
    elif c == 'z':
        return 9999
    elif c == ' ':
        return 0 
    
def main():
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    line = line.strip()
    line = int(line)

    for x in range(line):
        word = sys.stdin.readline()
        word = word.strip()
        # print('word:', word)

        alph = []
        output = ''
        for i in range(len(word)):
            alph.append(word[i])
        # print('alphabets:', alph)

        first = str(num(alph[0]))
        output += first
        # print('first:', first)

        for a in range(1, len(alph)):
            next = str(num(alph[a]))
            # print('next:', next)

            if next[0] == output[-1]:
                output = output + ' ' + next
            else:
                output += next
            # print("output", output)

        print(f'Case #{x+1}: {output}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Although I passed the first test case, I keep getting a runtime error for the second case, and I can't figure out why since I don't know the test case.

Comment: Can you get the complete traceback? If so, please provide it.

Comment: @MichaelRuth Coding challenge sites don't provide that kind of information.

Comment: There's no need to convert `word` to a list. You can iterate over the characters in a string the same as the elements in a list.

Comment: `num` would be better as a dictionary rather than a function with lots of `if/elif`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

When failing hidden submission tests, try to think of edge cases. Revisit the problem description to determine if there are any valid inputs you may not have accounted for.

You're currently reading a line of input as:

```py
word = sys.stdin.readline()
word = word.strip()
```

But the instructions say (emphasis mine):

> Each message will consist of only lowercase characters ‘a’–‘z’ **and space characters ‘ ’**. Pressing zero emits a space.

If you `.strip()` the input, you'll remove leading and trailing whitespace. The instructions never say the space characters can't be at the beginning or end of a line!

Here's a possible edge case:

```
1
```

(note that that's a single space on the second line). This gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/greg/programming/a.py", line 92, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/greg/programming/a.py", line 75, in main
    first = str(num(alph[0]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

You can handle it by changing the code to only remove the trailing newline, preserving leading and trailing spaces which are part of the input:

```py
word = sys.stdin.readline()
word = word.rstrip("\n")
```

Or use `word = word[:-1]`. Or iterate to `len(word) - 1`, which is likely the most efficient option.

After the fix, the degenerate input gives:

```
1
 
Case #1: 0
```

(Yes, there's still a single space on the second line)

After the change, the code passes Kattis' tests.